# Recieve json array from api in angular2

Tags: json, api, angular

I'm trying to receive a json array from an api and display it on page, i'm fairly certain that something is wrong with my service, i just don't know what.

```
   getAuctions(): Promise<Auction[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.auctionsUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().array as Auction[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

here is a response example

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Antik stol",
    "description": "En fin antik stol från 1800-talet",
    "startTime": "2016-12-13T10:00:00",
    "endTime": "2017-02-23T10:00:00",
    "imageUrl": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/antik-stol-som-stoppas-i-sammet-32935346.jpg",
    "categoryId": 1,
    "supplierId": 2,
    "buyNowPrice": 8000,
    "sold": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Antikt bord",
    "description": "En fint antikt bord",
    "startTime": "2016-12-10T10:00:00",
    "endTime": "2017-03-29T10:00:00",
    "imageUrl": "http://precisensan.com/antikforum/attachment.php?attachmentid=78277&stc=1&d=1292057973",
    "categoryId": 1,
    "supplierId": 1,
    "buyNowPrice": 18000,
    "sold": false
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I suspect that `response.json().array` might be wrong, you need to check what data is coming. It might be as simple as removing `.array` but not knowing how your data looks like it's hard to tell....

Comment: I think `response.json()` in your case is enough to get data

Answer (score -2):

AuctionService:

```
getAuctions() : Observable<Auction[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.auctionsUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError)
    }
```

AuctionComponent:

```
  getAuctions(): void {
    this.auctionService.getAuctions()
    .subscribe(auctions => this.auctions = auctions);
  }
```